# I have a database full of many databases and Tables on Hive, now how could I search and find the column of interest?

Tags: hive, impala, hue

Long in short that I realized that Hue(Hive/Impala) is not like Microsoft SQL server that you run the following to look for the Table of Interest.

Select * from information_schema.columns where column_name like '%The_Table_of_Interest%'

1st scenario: Imagine that I know what my Database is and I target my attention to the right table by searching through the table and find the column of interest.

2nd scenario: I don't know even what database I need to look for the right table and as a result the column of interest.

I realized that in Hue, there is no option to look for a column. All I can see is Table Search! [image: Hue Snapshot]

Having said that for the two above scenarios there should be a way to find the column of interest.

Scenario 2 is of course difficult to approach, however the 1st one looks a bit easier.

Now, I did my research and came of with running some code in Shell Command Line might be helpful to find the target column. However, that require some further investigation in the layer that I am not quite familiar.(Speaking of Metaset, etc.)

Therefore, here is my question.

Assume we are discussing the 1st scenario, now how can I search and find the columns while you have no knowledge about the tables at all. I can not take guesses and try every tables to find the right one to find the column that I am looking for. What would you suggest, and what is your strategy to approach? Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Good Day H2019

Here are some commands that should help you out to explore the different tables that you have access to:

Find a table or a database

`show tables like 'ben*'`

Look at the table definition

```
show create table <table>;
```

Get table information

```
describe my_table_01;
```

Get even more information

```
describe extended table_name
```

Get more information in a pretty format

```
describe formatted table_name;
```

If you have access to **Apache Range**r I also find it useful to look into tables permissions.  (And see who's using what)

**Apache Atlas** if you use it it helpful to see where data comes from.(It keeps data lineage information and may help to give you an understanding of how things work)

Don't forget you can look at **HDFS** to find databases, tables if they're in /hive/warehouse/.  This can also be helpful to understand when things are created.

Comment: Apache Ranger - is super useful to see what queries people are running and might help you see useful patterns.

Comment: Thank you Dharman and Matt. Yes, I need to access the whole metaset of data ingested to the datalake. Let's see how I can dig into it deeper.  Question: How can I deep into using HDFS and /hive/warehouse. Could you plz bring me an example?